# Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1444151296) (tried to allocate 134217728 bytes)

Tags: magento-1.7

I am getting fatal error while running file in magento. I am calculating and updating all product records price value in product table.

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1444151296) (tried to allocate 134217728 bytes)

Comment: It seems to be server related issue or script related issue. For the second case try to optimize your script (you should find a way to do thinks in a better way) or if it can't be try to increase the memory allowed to your php.ini or your server.

Comment: @axelparatre yes,  I also think the same. Thank you. My script is very lengthy means so much calculation is done.